# I got problem when have a expression in while loop's judge statement

Tags: c, while-loop

```
bool check_parenttheses(int p, int q)
    {
      int cnt = 1;
      int position = q - 1;
      int flag = position - p;
      if(tokens[p].type == '(' && tokens[q].type == ')')
      {
        while(flag)
        {
          if(tokens[flag].type == '(')
            cnt --;
          else if(tokens[flag].type == ')')
            cnt ++;
          
          if(cnt <= 0)
            return false;
          
          flag --;
        }
    
        if(cnt == 1)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
```

I use this function to judge if a expression is inside a pair of ()

p(0) is the begin of the expression and q(17) is the end

but the while-loop's judge statement has some problem.
The first time in while-loop, flag becomes 16. But when I come to the `while(flag)` the second time,
flag suddenly becomes 477218604

Comment: Is some code missing? Why are you testing `position - p` if only `position` is changing and `p` is always `0`?

Comment: Could you show your `token[]` array/

Comment: is ```cnt``` supposed to be ```p```?

Comment: Here is the whole function:

Comment: @shikyeee, It is best to edit your question to have formatted code. It is hard to read code in a comment

Comment: sounds like [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but without a [mre], impossible to diagnose. What's `p`? What's `q`? What's `tokens`, how is it initialized? Where all possible, we should be able to copy and paste the code in your question, compile and run, and see the same behavior. There are too many unknowns here, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: @yano the whole code is so big that

Comment: Ok,, read the [mre] link. That _doesn't mean_ post your whole code. It means post the least amount of code possible that exhibits the problematic behavior. That _does_ mean you might have to do some extra work to create one. And more often than not, you'll discover the problem yourself while creating it. I do now see you told us the values of `p` and `q`, but `tokens` is still a mystery.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Are you trying to find balanced parenthesis in an expression? [balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/)